# Error running mongodb as service on Centos 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I've got a VPS with Centos 7, But when I try to run MongoDB as service I get the following message:

```
Apr 06 03:11:46 server.backupserver.com systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Apr 06 03:11:46 server.backupserver.com mongod[3767]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Apr 06 03:11:46 server.backupserver.com mongod[3767]: forked process: 3769
Apr 06 03:11:49 server.backupserver.com systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid (yet?) after start: Too many levels of symbolic links
Apr 06 03:13:17 server.backupserver.com systemd[1]: mongod.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Apr 06 03:13:17 server.backupserver.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Apr 06 03:13:17 server.backupserver.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Apr 06 03:13:17 server.backupserver.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

I tested the responses from another topics, but it doesn't work yet.

The "var/run/mongodb" directory and the file "mongod.pid" has the right permissions and user (mongod).

Please, help

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be a message that [systemd can produce under a variety of conditions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=systemd+Too+many+levels+of+symbolic+links&ia=web). To troubleshoot:

1. Start with a pristine Docker, Vagrant, VirtualBox etc. image of CentOS 7.
2. Follow the [official MongoDB installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/).

If you succeed, follow the official installation instructions on your VPS.